# Cond inside let doesn't work properly

Tags: conditional-statements, common-lisp, let

I'm having a trouble with some Common Lisp code. I have two functions similars to the functions below:

```
(defun recursive-func (func lst num)
  (let ((test
          (some-func func
                     (first lst)
                     (first (rest lst))
                     num))
        (next
          (recursive-func func
                          (rest lst)
                          num)))

    (cond ((null (rest lst)) nil)
          ((null test) next)
          (t (cons test next)))))

(defun some-func (func a b num)
  (if (> a b)
      nil
      (funcall func a b num)))
```

When the list has only one element I want `recursive-func` return `nil`, but it doesn't and calls `some-func` generating a evaluation abort because `b` is `nil`. Here is a trace of execution:

```
CL-USER> (recursive-func #'(lambda(x y z) (+ x y z)) '(1 2 3 4 5) 5)
  0: (RECURSIVE-FUNC #<FUNCTION (LAMBDA (X Y Z)) {10035F6ABB}> (1 2 3 4 5) 5)
    1: (SOME-FUNC #<FUNCTION (LAMBDA (X Y Z)) {10035F6ABB}> 1 2 5)
    1: SOME-FUNC returned 8
    1: (RECURSIVE-FUNC #<FUNCTION (LAMBDA (X Y Z)) {10035F6ABB}> (2 3 4 5) 5)
      2: (SOME-FUNC #<FUNCTION (LAMBDA (X Y Z)) {10035F6ABB}> 2 3 5)
      2: SOME-FUNC returned 10
      2: (RECURSIVE-FUNC #<FUNCTION (LAMBDA (X Y Z)) {10035F6ABB}> (3 4 5) 5)
        3: (SOME-FUNC #<FUNCTION (LAMBDA (X Y Z)) {10035F6ABB}> 3 4 5)
        3: SOME-FUNC returned 12
        3: (RECURSIVE-FUNC #<FUNCTION (LAMBDA (X Y Z)) {10035F6ABB}> (4 5) 5)
          4: (SOME-FUNC #<FUNCTION (LAMBDA (X Y Z)) {10035F6ABB}> 4 5 5)
          4: SOME-FUNC returned 14
          4: (RECURSIVE-FUNC #<FUNCTION (LAMBDA (X Y Z)) {10035F6ABB}> (5) 5)
            5: (SOME-FUNC #<FUNCTION (LAMBDA (X Y Z)) {10035F6ABB}> 5 NIL 5)
; Evaluation aborted on #<TYPE-ERROR expected-type: NUMBER datum: NIL>.
```

I hope someone would can help me, thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The bindings in `let` are evaluated first, and only then you perform the tests in the `cond`.
You need only change a bit:

```
(defun recursive-func (func list num)
  (if (null (rest list))
      nil
      (let ((test (some-func func
                             (first list)
                             (first (rest list))
                             num))
            (next (recursive-func func
                                  (rest list)
                                  num)))
        (cond ((null test) next)
              (t (cons test next))))))
```

Note that the `cond` could also be written:

```
(if test (cons test next) next)
```

With your example:

```
(recursive-func (lambda (x y z) (+ x y z))
                '(1 2 3 4 5)
                5)
=> (8 10 12 14)
```

Alternatively, here is how you could decompose the task (in the REPL):

```
> (maplist (lambda (list)
             (list
              (first list)
              (second list)))
           '(1 2 3 4 5))
=> ((1 2) (2 3) (3 4) (4 5) (5 NIL))
```

Prefer [`SECOND`](http://www.lispworks.com/reference/HyperSpec/Body/f_firstc.htm) instead of `(first (rest ...))`.
The last result is bound in the REPL to the variable [`*`](http://www.lispworks.com/reference/HyperSpec/Body/a_st.htm). Remove the last (useless) pair with [`BUTLAST`](http://www.lispworks.com/reference/HyperSpec/Body/f_butlas.htm):

```
(butlast *)
=> ((1 2) (2 3) (3 4) (4 5))
```

Then, for each couple in this list, call your function -- here it is just [`+`](http://www.lispworks.com/reference/HyperSpec/Body/a_pl.htm). Notice the use of [`DESTRUCTURING-BIND`](http://www.lispworks.com/reference/HyperSpec/Body/m_destru.htm):

```
(mapcar (lambda (list)
          (destructuring-bind (a b) list
            (+ a b 5)))
        *)
=> (8 10 12 14)
```

So, basically, your function can be written as:

```
(defun map-pair-funcall (function list number)
  (mapcar (lambda (pair)
            (destructuring-bind (a b) pair
              (funcall function a b number)))
          (butlast (maplist (lambda (list)
                              (list (first list) (second list)))
                            list))))
```

And thus:

```
(map-pair-funcall #'+ '(1 2 3 4 5) 5)
=> (8 10 12 14)
```

---

Edit:

I missed the case where the supplied function might return NIL. Wrap the form calling `mapcar` by `(remove NIL (mapcar ...))` to filter that out.

---

You can perform all that in one iteration by using [`MAPCON`](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/f_mapc_.htm). The function iterates over sublists, and concatenates the resulting lists. The function being called should thus return list, and when you return NIL, the result are simply discarded.

Let's define `ensure-list` (or use the one from [Alexandria](https://gitlab.common-lisp.net/alexandria/alexandria)):

```
(defun ensure-list (expr)
  (if (listp expr) expr (list expr)))
```

The function wraps the returned value in a list, except if it is already a list (in particular, NIL). And then, the function is defined as follows:

```
(defun map-pair-funcall (function list number)
  (mapcon (lambda (list)
            (and (second list)
                 (ensure-list (funcall function
                                       (first list)
                                       (second list)
                                       number))))
          list))
```

You could also [`LOOP`](http://www.lispworks.com/reference/HyperSpec/Body/m_loop.htm):

```
(defun map-pair-funcall (function list number)
  (loop 
    for (a b) on list
    for result = (and b (funcall function a b number))
    when result
      collect result))
```

Comment: Thanks so much. The first solution works for me but the improvement with ´MAPLIST´ doesn't cover the case when some of the calls to the function whos passed as argument return ´nil´. It still in the resultant list and it have to be removed.